# A word meaning a serious claim or demand not meant to be followed through with

Tags: meaning, american-english

If someone says "Sue me" in a completely serious manner but not expecting it to actually happen, what is a word to describe that?

Comment: A *bluff*, perhaps? Or are you thinking of *empty threat*?

Comment: "Hollow threat" is another common term.

Answer (score 2):

If the listener knows you don't mean it, it's irony. If, on the other hand, it's only a display of confidence to discourage any action, it's a bluff.

> - [**irony**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony) - - "the use of words that mean the opposite of what is really meant."
> - [**bluff**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bluff) - a false display of confidence meant to deceive or mislead.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bluff or empty threat if the other party said: 'I will sue you.' By contrast 'sue me' is a challenge or dare.

'Sue me' isn't a claim or demand, nor is it something 'not meant to be followed through with.'

'Sue me' might be a taunt, a provocation or invitation but it could be ‘followed through with’ only by its originator… The end result might seem similar but the respondent can only… uh… respond to the protagonist’s action.

Any response will ‘follow’ not ‘follow through.’

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

It's **taking a stand** (no pun intended).

> Adopt a firm position about an issue, as in She was more than willing
>   to take a stand on abortion rights. This idiom alludes to the military
>   sense of stand, “hold one's ground against an enemy.” [Mid-1800s ]
>   Also see: make a stand

The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary
Copyright © 2002, 2001, 1995 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company.

It's an act of **defiance**

> 1. a daring or bold resistance to authority or to any opposing force.
> 2. open disregard; contempt (often followed by of):

defiance. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved January 9, 2017 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/defiance

It's **recalcitrant** behavior.

> [T]he manager worried that the recalcitrant employee would try to undermine his authority.
>
> Long before any human was dubbed "recalcitrant" in English (that first occurred, as best we know, in one of William Thackeray's works in 1843), there were stubborn mules (and horses) kicking back their heels. The ancient Romans noted as much (Pliny the Elder among them), and they had a word for it - "recalcitrare," which literally means "to kick back." (Its root calc-, meaning "heel," is also the root of "calcaneus," the large bone of the heel in humans.) Certainly Roman citizens in Pliny's time were sometimes willful and hardheaded - as attested by various Latin words meaning "stubborn" - but it wasn’t until later that writers of Late Latin applied recalcitrare and its derivative adjective to humans who were stubborn as mules.

*Recalcitrant* example and etymology from: "Recalcitrant." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 9 Jan. 2017.